# iphone : using Background location services is stopped after a little time

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, location, locationmanager

i'm trying to get a location and compare it with a location online all that happen in background
the method i create is working fine using background location service but after a minute or so the location icon in the status bar is getting disappear and the method is not getting called any longer

here is the code

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {


    double  lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    double  lon = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    NSURL * locationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://somedomainname.com/iphoneLocation?lat=%f&lon=%f",lat,lon]];
    NSData * responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:locationURL];
    NSString* aStr;
    aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];



    if ([aStr isEqualToString:@"out Of Any Knowen Range"] ){
            UILocalNotification *notify =[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            notify.alertAction = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"View"];
            notify.fireDate=nil;
            notify.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New Data Occured"];
            notify.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            NSLog(@"Local notification should display");
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notify];
        }

}
```

and in the viewDid load i'm using something like this

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    locationManager.delegate = self;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocation *userLocation = [locationManager location];
```

so what is the wrong with it

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your **AppName-Info.plist** file by adding a key `Required background modes` with an item with value `App registers for location updates`. Another thing I think you should do as you connect online and this may not happen very fast, so the operation that you connect online, post the location and wait for response should start in another thread and meanwhile if you have received another location from `CLLocationManager` and your previous request has not finished yet to skip posting the new location...

Comment: i'm using app registers for location as i've said in the post.. and for the slow connection is not the case .. the problem is the location icon in the status bar is disappearing after a minute or so as if it's done checking or suspended !!

Comment: Try comment the lines where you connect online and wait for response, if it doesn't stop then the problem is that you connect online, because this slows down how fast `didUpdateLocation` method returns... and you should implement it the way I described in my answer...

Comment: thanks..i've tried your idea of commenting the url and same happens :)

Comment: do you call somewhere `stopUpdatingLocation`?

Comment: no .. should i .. i supposed that it getting called because it's in the background!!

Comment: If you have modified the AppName-Info.plist file it shouldn't stop... What do you do in the `didFailWithError` delegate method?

Comment: didFailWithError is never get called

Comment: so is there a way that we know?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the Location Manager is getting released somewhere and therefore not sending any more updates.

Have you tried setting the location manager to a retained property in your view controller?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager
```

Comment: i did that and still it stopped after 20 seconds

Comment: The strange thing is .. it's working fine on simulator ..but any devices no luck

Comment: I assume you've tried commenting out all the networking code and leaving only a log statement in the didUpdateTo callback?  Is the app crashing at all?  If it's not crashing, it probably means the view controller is getting unloaded somewhere and the location manager released.